# Arguments object returning unexpected values

Tags: javascript

Why is the arguments object giving unexpected results here

```
console.log("the arguments are" + arguments);  
console.log(arguments); // returns the correct arguments
```

The first one  returns `the arguments are[object Arguments]`
while the second one returns correct arguments... why is that??? when i concatenate a string with it?

Comment: `console.log("the arguments are" , arguments);  `

Comment: @ArunPJohny you mean we can also display in console by splitting them with a coma?

Answer (score 1):

Because `console.log` does different things in the background. Your first call

```
console.log("Arguments: "+arguments);
```

Will call the `toString` method in the background. The second call

```
console.log(arguments);
```

Prints the object correctly, cause it's not converted to a string ( the `toString` method is not called ).

You get the same result as the first one when you do this:

```
console.log(arguments.toString());
```

What you might want to do is this:

```
console.log("Arguments:", arguments);
```

You can add as many objects as you want by separating them with a comma.